# error: binding reference of type 'Foam::Field<double>&' to 'const Foam::Field<double>' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

I am having this classical compilation error saying that I am neglecting the const property of an object:

```
In file included from lnInclude/RBFInterpolation.H:172:0,
                 from toto.H:46,
                 from toto.C:26:
lnInclude/RBFInterpolationTemplates.C: In instantiation of 'Foam::tmp<Foam::Field<Type> > Foam::RBFInterpolation::interpolate(const Foam::Field<Type>&) const [with Type = double]':
toto.C:873:77:   required from here
lnInclude/RBFInterpolationTemplates.C:65:18: error: binding reference of type 'Foam::Field<double>&' to 'const Foam::Field<double>' discards qualifiers
     Field<Type>& result = tresult();
```

Here is the method from which I call interpolate:

```
void Foam::toto::calcPtarget(const volScalarField& PIn)
{
scalarField& ctrlField_ = ctrlField();

forAll(tocPress, toCellI)
{
    label cellI = tocPress[toCellI];

    point curNode_ = meshRef_.cellCentres()[cellI];
    controlPoints_[cellI] = curNode_;
    ctrlField_[cellI] = Pref[cellI];
}

vectorField toInterPoints_ = interSurf_.faceCentres();
forAll(toInterPoints_, faceCentreI)
{
    dataPoints_[faceCentreI] = toInterPoints_[faceCentreI];
}
scalarField& controlField =  ctrlField_;
scalarField interpolatedMotion = interpolation_.interpolate(controlField);
}
```

And the method interpolate itself :

```
template<class Type>
Foam::tmp<Foam::Field<Type> > Foam::RBFInterpolation::interpolate
(
    const Field<Type>& ctrlField
) const
{
tmp<Field<Type> > tresult
(
    new Field<Type>(dataPoints_.size(), pTraits<Type>::zero)
);

Field<Type>& result = tresult();


return tresult;
}
```

I have tried declaring interpolated motion as const or even ctrlField in my header as a mutable const and use that instead without success. Another alternative would be to call interpolation_.interpolate() from a const method?

Comment: Please provide a [repro]. We don't know what `tresult()` does. It seems to be returning a `const` reference.

Comment: There are several things missing from the question, but I'd like to see what constructors `Foam::Field` provides.

Comment: It looks like the example code needs both more and less. More context so that all identifiers are defined. Less extraneous code; for example, probably the only part of `calcPtarget` that is needed is the call to `interpolate` (and that call could probably be moved to a `main` function for simplicity).